# In a secure view the filter which has a date casting is not pushing the filter to the view

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We created a view on top of  "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY". When we run a query on the view with filter as where start_time::date >=current_date::date -7, the filter is not getting pushed to the query_history view. The query is bringing all the records and then applying the filter on the records. Is this a defect with snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the reason for this issue. It looks like when you cast a field like what i was dong above to get the data(start_time::date >=current_date::date -7), the predicates are not pushed down the view. By the way, we also moved away from creating a view now on top of the account usage view("SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"). We have decided to unload the data from this view every day and build our observatory layer on top of it. This helped us run the queries much faster with less credits.

Answer (score 0):

When I run following script I only see filtered dates. Share your query to see the problem

```js
create or replace secure view sample_view as

select * from snowflake.account_usage.query_history ;

select distinct start_time::date from sample_view where start_time::date >=current_date::date -2;
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, may be I have not explained it well. The result is not an issue. Please look at your query profile and see if the filter is getting pushed to the view snowflake.account_usage.query_history. The requirement is to bring only the records which meets the filter from snowflake.account_usage.query_history. Currently it is bringing everything from snowflake.account_usage.query_history and then applying the filter